# `gpg: key XXX not found: Not found` when listing public keys

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Recently, when doing a `gpg --list-keys <email>` against my own personal email, I've noticed that GnuPG started giving me a number of errors before proceeding with normal output:

```
$ gpg --list-keys intelfx@intelfx.name
gpg: key "09F4605E1379E1909AAC87B10874248396A58CF5" not found: Not found
gpg: key "1141EF4806D03A7AFFF4B48AE31AF27D2BF9FD6F" not found: Not found
gpg: key "14EF360E24BC1C67B2DD718E985504164F3E0D3B" not found: Not found
gpg: key "6879E2F83421AC49A1368507AE906D1F50408E4E" not found: Not found
gpg: key "86790DCBF818ACA719CD3DD57032FFA24FFFA472" not found: Not found
gpg: key "893386E8012237AB6828522B6B8A2EF65CD744E2" not found: Not found
gpg: key "BDCE5CA5E5BDECA71DFC9B23C679EF7A1D64DDC1" not found: Not found
gpg: key "D3A913798447EE9C289715DE4270CFE164C5E325" not found: Not found
gpg: key "DC309E6872FC6DF6C61D1C3FC1F1504ACCD1403B" not found: Not found
pub   rsa4096/0x281015BE2CAC2CBC 2015-12-19 [C]
      Key fingerprint = 31EF DDC9 8A18 FA61 0D38  9A3D 2810 15BE 2CAC 2CBC
uid                   [ultimate] Ivan Shapovalov <intelfx@intelfx.name>
uid                   [ultimate] Ivan Shapovalov <intelfx100@gmail.com>
sub   rsa4096/0x7BDE17C8E4E30E9D 2015-12-19 [S]
      Key fingerprint = E4DF 27BC 899C C769 C994  519C 7BDE 17C8 E4E3 0E9D
sub   rsa4096/0x619341A697B609C7 2015-12-19 [E]
      Key fingerprint = 9F1E 297F 99D0 8C54 518C  6E8D 6193 41A6 97B6 09C7

<... rest of my keys ...>
```

Performing `gpg --list-keys` against any other UID does not lead to the problem. I do not remember having any keys with those fingerprints, and attempts to export, delete or edit those keys using the shown fingerprints do not succeed.

I'm not exactly sure what does GnuPG try to tell me with all those "Not found" keys: somehow it simultaneously "knows" these IDs and "does not know" them. How do I make GnuPG forget them?

Comment: Try to delete them, if not needed ?

Comment: @harrymc as stated in the question, attempts to export, delete or edit those keys do not succeed (i. e. GnuPG simply prints the same error).

Comment: With which command have you tried to delete them? Which Linux distribution? Give this a try : [Y PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/y-ppa-manager-0084-released-finally.html).

Comment: @harrymc `gpg --delete-keys`. Distribution does not matter, assume self-built (GnuPG 2.2.x). Why would I need a PPA manager?

Comment: I just saw who you are. Yes, you don't need it.

Comment: I had this problem as well with my deleted keys and found that for me the "not found" fingerprints were from old tofu bindings. If you're using tofu trying checking the output of `sqlite3 ~/.gnupg/tofu.db .dump` for the fingerprints.

Comment: @JoshBrobst That was it! Could you please write an answer so that I could give it the upvote and the checkmark it deserves?

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'll write an answer but I'm unsure if my method of just editing the database manually is the correct solution - did you find a way to use `gpg` itself to delete the bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who use a tofu-based trust model, this warning can be caused by an
existing key conflicting with the fingerprint of a nonexistent key. This
situation can be seen by looking for the "not found" fingerprints in the tofu
database contents:

```sh
sqlite3 ~/.gnupg/tofu.db .dump
```

This may occur, for example, after importing two keys with the same user id and
deleting one of them:

```sh
temp_home() {
    GNUPGHOME=$(mktemp -d)/gnupg
    mkdir -- "$GNUPGHOME"
    chmod 700 -- "$GNUPGHOME"
    printf 'trust-model tofu\ntofu-default-policy unknown\n' >"$GNUPGHOME/gpg.conf"
    export GNUPGHOME
    printf 'Using GnuPG home: %s\n' "$GNUPGHOME"
}

uid='Alice Smith <alice@example.com>'

temp_home
gpg --yes --batch --passphrase '' --quick-generate-key "$uid"
gpg --yes --batch --passphrase '' --quick-generate-key "$uid"
fpr1=$(gpg --with-colons -k "$uid" | awk -F : '$1 == "fpr" { print $10; exit }')
old_home=$GNUPGHOME

temp_home
gpg --homedir "$old_home" --export | gpg --import
gpg --list-public-keys  # Creates tofu.db
gpg --batch --delete-keys "$fpr1"

# We now get the warning
gpg --list-public-keys
# Notice the old fingerprint is still in the conflict column
sqlite3 -- "$GNUPGHOME/tofu.db" "SELECT * FROM bindings WHERE conflict != ''"
```

However, I'm uncertain what the recommended course of action to resolve this is.
When this happened to me personally, I had never used the deleted keys for
anything so I only had to remove the old keys and the conflict from the tofu
database's `bindings` table:

```sql
DELETE FROM bindings WHERE fingerprint = '<old fingerprint>';
UPDATE bindings SET conflict = '' WHERE fingerprint = '<new fingerprint>';
```

In cases of used but deleted keys, other tables in the database may reference
the binding record, in which case those other records probably have to be
removed as well. Again, I don't know how to resolve this with `gpg` itself.